# Action button show app on foreground

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

If I tap the notification, it will open the app, but when I add button to the notification, and the user press a button the app stay on background, I want the same operation as tap on the notification (open the app on frontend)

Its possible?

Solved! Thanks for the answer:

```
    let actionButton = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    actionButton.identifier = identifier
    actionButton.title = title
    actionButton.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
    actionButton.authenticationRequired = true
    actionButton.destructive = false
```

Comment: The purpose of the actions is to allow the user to perform some action without needing to open your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `activationMode` of your action to `UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground` if you want the app to be opened by that action.